# Change ASP.NET Core 2 Razor Pages default directory name to wwwroot

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

One of the new key feature of ASP.NET Core 2.0 is Razor Pages.
I've been able use them in the default `/Pages` folder and any other custom folder like `/RazorPages` by putting this in my `startup.cs` file.

```
services.AddMvc().WithRazorPagesRoot("/RazorPages");
```

as described in this article : http://www.talkingdotnet.com/change-asp-net-core-razor-pages-default-directory-name/

But when I try to make the default Razor Pages directory the `/wwwroot` folder, it ignores any of my namespaces or models declared in the "code-behind" .cs file. Like this:

```
services.AddMvc().WithRazorPagesRoot("/wwwroot");
```

I'm guessing because .cs files cannot be accessed from the public facing `/wwwroot` folder.

Does anyone know how to make the Razor Pages default directory `/wwwroot`?

I think the Razor Pages feature will be greatly used in the future.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to edit your project file to actually compile `.cs` files in `wwwroot`; the default template excludes them.

However, you shouldn't do this; `wwwroot` is meant to have public-facing content only, not server-side code.

Comment: Thank you @SLaks. To add more detail to your answer, I changed the .csproj file and added an ItemGroup: <Compile Include="wwwroot\**\*.cs" />. This worked and now I can have Razor Pages and their code-behind files in the /wwwroot folder.

Comment: I agree with SLaks you really should not do this. You risk publically exposing your source code. There is a reason it was designed to be in a separate folder structure.